# Verificar se tem algum checkbox checado e habilitar botão

Tags: jquery

Como fazer em JQuery, uma função que verifica se existe algum checkbox selecionado, se existir algum ele habilita o botão de exclusão, se existir mais de 1 ele coloca o texto no plural.

Fiz o seguinte código:

[**DEMO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/KG2Zy/1/)

[versão 2.0 atualização do fiddler:](http://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/KG2Zy/5/)

OBS: fiz o exemplo abaixo em javascript puro, porém gostaria que fosse em JQUERY. E ele ainda tem algum erro que só habilita quando o último é marcado.

```
<script>
function verificaChecks() {
        var checados=0;
        var aChk = document.getElementsByName("chk_IDDel"); 
        for (var i=0;i<aChk.length;i++){ 
            if (aChk[i].checked == true){ 
                checados++;
                 document.getElementById('btn_Deletar').removeAttribute("disabled");
                if(checados >1)
                {
                    document.getElementById("btn_Deletar").value='Deletar registroS';
                }
            }  else {
                document.getElementById('btn_Deletar').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");

                 if(checados >1)
                {
                    document.getElementById("btn_Deletar").value='Deletar registroS';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("btn_Deletar").value='Deletar registro';
                }

            }
        }
    } 
</script>

    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk_IDDel" id="chk_IDDel" value='1' onchange="verificaChecks()" />
            <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk_IDDel" id="chk_IDDel" value='2' onchange="verificaChecks()" />
            <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk_IDDel" id="chk_IDDel" value='3' onchange="verificaChecks()" />
            <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk_IDDel" id="chk_IDDel" value='4' onchange="verificaChecks()" />
            <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="deletar registro" id="btn_Deletar" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="true"  />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remova os `onchange="verificaChecks()"` do `inputs` e faça assim com jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
    $("[name='chk_IDDel']").change(function(){
        var countSelected = $("input[name=chk_IDDel]:checked").length;
        var $btnDeletar = $('#btn_Deletar');
        $btnDeletar.prop("disabled", countSelected == 0);
        $btnDeletar.val('Deletar registro' + (countSelected > 1 ? 's' : ''));
    });
});
```

[Exemplo online atualizado com as sugestões dos comentarios.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/AdRFS/9/)

Comment: por isso gosto do jquery..ficou pequeno o código. como verificar o plural ou não count >1 mudar texto?

Comment: @Fernando, use `$("input[name=chk_IDDel]:checked").length;` ao inves de dar loop em todos os checkbox, [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/KG2Zy/6/) tem um exemplo se for de alguma ajuda

Comment: edita sua resposta para colocar o plural..mas funcionou..obrigado. http://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/AdRFS/1/

Comment: @Rodrigo, obrigado pela dica, atualizei minha resposta com sua sugestão. ^^

Comment: @Dorathoto ainda pode fazer o código mais pequeno (http://jsfiddle.net/AdRFS/7/). Fernando: `+1`

Comment: @Sergio, muito boa sua solução, atualizei meu exemplo e minha resposta, obrigado pela dica.